# how to send an array with checkbox data via ajax to a php script

Tags: php, jquery, html

have another question, to do with ajax and how to send data from a checkbox form without any page reload/redirect, i have the following code, here's the markup:

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <title>guild</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="dive">
         <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="userList[]" value="together" />together<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="userList[]" value="we" />we<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="userList[]" value="made" />made<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="userList[]" value="it" />it<br />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="yeah we did it!" />
         </form>
      </div>
      and here's the jquery:
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min (1).js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
         //when the button is clicked
         $("#submit").click(function(){
         //put the checked data into an array
         var userList= $('#dive input[type=checkbox]:checked').serializeArray();
         //send the data without page reload/refresh/redirect
         $.post("guild.php", {userList: userList},function(userList)
         {
         });
         });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

so the checked data is supposed to be sent to a php file which writes it to a file, here's the script:

```
<?php
//get sent data
$userList=$_POST['userList'];
//open file to be written to
$fp=fopen("guild.html", 'a');
//write data into file
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($userList);$i++) 
{
fwrite($fp, "<div class='gn'>."userList[$i]"."<br>"."</div>");
}
//close file
fclose($fp);
?>
```

i know that this is a very simple question, but i just can't get it to work, even after reading other answers. i need the checked data to be sent in form of an array, not a string. so how would i change the jquery part to make it work?thanks in advance for the help, i am an extreme beginner!

Comment: Are you using Firebug (or similar) to debug jQuery's POST request?

Comment: Check the XHR tab in Chrome, and see if the request is actually making out. You should be able to see the data that you are sending also.

Comment: JQuery's [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method documentation has the information you want... Do a search on the page for the word `array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [jQuery post documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#example-2), you should be sending the post data array like so:

```
$.post("guild.php", { "userList[]": userList }...
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, but i have made the changes suggested and still nothing happens, the page just reloads and no data is sent to the script, here are the changes:      $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var userList= $('#dive input[type="checkbox"]:checked').serializeArray();
    $.post("guild.php", {"userList[]": [userList]});
    });
    });  nothing happens, it would be nice if you could kindly sho me how to send form data from checkboxes without page reload/redirect, thanks in advance.

Comment: Per your comment, you're syntax is still incorrect - it should be `{"userList[]": userList }`. `userList` not `[userList]`.

Answer (score 0):

I use that script and I receive this:

```
Array ( [0] => [object Object] [1] => [object Object] )
```

I use this code:

```
function add_apartament ()
    {
var vedere= $('#vedere input[type=checkbox]:checked').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/ajax/add_apartament_action.php",
            data: { 
                    'vedere[]':vedere
                  },
            success: function (msg) {

                $("#action").html(msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });


    }
```

And php...

```
<?php

print_r($_POST['vedere']);

?>
```